# Ubuntu 15.10 wifi requires network-services restart in order to connect

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

New install of Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit. In order to get the wifi to see available networks and connect, I have to issue the command:

```
sudo services network-manager restart
```

Once I do that, it sees the networks and auto-connects. But, I have to do this *every time* I start the system. Clearly everything works, but not automatically at startup.

What do I need to do in order for it to connect at startup and not require the above command just to see and connect to wifi?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was the USB WiFi adapter I was using (Belkin N150 Wireless N USB Adapter) was not playing nice with Ubuntu 15.10. When I switched to a PCIe WiFi adapter (TP-Link Wireless N PCI Express Adapter TL-WN881ND) it worked from startup and I did not have to restart network services to see networks and log into my default network.